# Dealing with unsized arrays in Go and Windows API

Tags: windows, go, winapi, etw

What is the idiomatic way to deal with unsized arrays in Go? I'm working on the ETW wrappers and the [TdhGetEventInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tdh/nf-tdh-tdhgeteventinformation) function fills in the provided memory buffer with event information. The event metadata is represented by [TRACE_EVENT_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tdh/ns-tdh-_trace_event_info) structure, which has an array member declared as:

```
EVENT_PROPERTY_INFO EventPropertyInfoArray[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
```

I'm calling the `TdhGetEventInformation` function in a way that the provided buffer has enough space to populate event properties array:

```
var bufferSize uint32 = 4096
buffer := make([]byte, bufferSize)

tdhGetEventInformation.Call(
   uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(eventRecord)),
   0, 0, 
   uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0])),
   uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bufferSize)),
)
```

However, since I'm tempting to model the Go counterpart struct with `EventPropertyInfoArray` field as

```
EventPropertyInfoArray [1]EventPropertyInfo
```

the compiler is not able to re dimension the array according to the number of available properties for each event, so I end up with one-array item.

Do you have any smart ideas on how handle this edge case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want a variable sized array in Go? Use a slice?

```
EventPropertyInfoArray [1]EventPropertyInfo
```

Would be

```
EventPropertyInfoArray []EventPropertyInfo
```

If you have a rough idea of a maximum it could hold you could make an array using make something like this, but this wouldn't help you out in declaring a struct:

```
EventPropertyInfoArray = make([]EventPropertyInfo, len, capacity)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried by converting the array to slice, but all I get is a slice with bizarre lengths of invalid entries (attempting to index the slice leads to unexpected fault address panic)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error, I managed to get the right slice from the backing array through standard technique for turning arrays into slices:

```
 properties := (*[1 << 30]EventPropertyInfo)(unsafe.Pointer(&trace.EventPropertyInfoArray[0]))[:trace.PropertyCount:trace.PropertyCount]
```